# How to change value of java superclass read only field in groovy?

Tags: groovy, spock

I got class:

```
public abstract class AbstractEntity {
    
  @Getter
  @Column(nullable = false, unique = true, updatable = false)
  private UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();

}
```

and test:

```
 def 'should be transitive: if x.equals(y) and y.equals(z) then x.equals(z)'() {
        given:
        AbstractEntity place = new Place()
        AbstractEntity secondPlace = new Place()
        AbstractEntity thirdPlace = new Place()

        and: 'all entities has same uuid what makes them equal'
        secondPlace.changeUuid(place.uuid)
        thirdPlace.changeUuid(place.uuid)
```

line `secondPlace.changeUuid(place.uuid)` throws exception: `groovy.lang.ReadOnlyPropertyException: Cannot set readonly property`

How can I set this field value without using java reflection?

Comment: Why are you hiding the code under test from us here? Where is the `Place` class? What does method `changeUuid` do? Why do you think that an incoherent set of code snippets which nobody can compile and run would help anyone to answer your question? You are interested in results, I guess. So give the community here something to work with. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have an attribute in the @Column 'updatable = false. My first reaction is to think that this stops variables from being updated.

There is also no @Setter annotation which could be useful in this scenario.

Then you could use this method within your test.